# Display only time in java script countdown timer

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I am using a javascript countdown timer with code from [here](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/)

My code is :

```
 var myCountdown2 = new Countdown({
   time: 90,
   width:200,
   height:80,
   rangeHi:"minute"  // <- no comma on last item!
 });
```

I want to show only seconds eg. I have 1 min 30 Sec. And it is displayed as it is 1:30. But I want to show only 90 seconds instead of 1 min 30 Sec. Is there any code to show only seconds in that javascript function?

Comment: Convert 1:30 to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Convert time to seconds. Here is the code to convert to seconds

```
function toSeconds(str) {
var pieces = str.split(":");
var result = (Number(pieces[0]) * 60) + Number(pieces[1]);
return(result.toFixed(3));
}

document.write(toSeconds("1:30"));
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.But if i insert 90 sec. even then it displays 1:30. You can see in code i insert time :90